# qgis2web - "popups on hover" function disabled with "layer groups"

Tags: qgis2web

I noticed that the "popups on hover" function is disabled if I set the "layer groups" in the layer.js file.
Can you recommend a solution?

I modified:

**layer.js** organizing the layers into groups

```
var layersList = [

new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Basemap',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [lyr_GoogleTerrain_0,lyr_GoogleSatellite_1,lyr_OpenStreetMap_2,lyr_SfondoBianco_3]
            }),

new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Cartografia generale',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [lyr_ConfiniComunali_30,lyr_LimiteRiserva_31]
            }),
            
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Itinerari Monte Paganuccio',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [lyr_n534_104km_h320m_4,lyr_n533_187km_h550m_5,lyr_n532_72km_h140m_200_6,lyr_n531b_850km_h160m_230_7,lyr_n531a_800km_h180m_200_8]
                }), 
            
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Itinerari Monte Pietralata',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [lyr_n523_189km_h650m_9,lyr_n522b_105km_h280m_345_10,lyr_n522a_800km_h200m_215_11,lyr_n521_120km_h446m_345_12]
                }),         

new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Itinerari Fondovalle',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [lyr_n511_600km_h0m_130_13]
                }),
            
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Sentieri Monte Paganuccio',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [lyr_n452a_480km_h205m_315_14,lyr_n452_900km_h375m_530_15,lyr_n451_510km_h811m_335_16,lyr_n450a_380km_h375m_230_17]
                }),

new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Sentieri Monte Pietralata',
            fold: 'open',
            layers: [lyr_n450_530km_h422m_300_18,lyr_n449b_096km_h49m_050_19,lyr_n449a_077km_h20m_040_20,lyr_n449_277km_h495m_240_21,lyr_n446a_080km_h82m_035_22,lyr_n446_370km_h539m_240_23,lyr_n441b_020km_h47m_025_24,lyr_n441a_120km_h124m_110_25,lyr_n441_385km_h346m_220_26,lyr_n440b_191km_h50m_055_27,lyr_n440a_123km_h222m_050_28,lyr_n440_68km_h423m_500_29]
                }),     

new ol.layer.Group({
            title: 'Difficoltà percorso:',
            layers: [
            
                new ol.layer.Group({
                title: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="sidebar-v2/ordisabeba/impegnativo.png"></img> <i class="fas fa-bicycle"></i> Impegnativo (MTB)<p></p>',
                layers: []
                }),
                
                new ol.layer.Group({
                title: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="sidebar-v2/ordisabeba/escursionistico.png"></img> <i class="fas fa-hiking"></i> Escursionistico',
                layers: []
                }),
                
                new ol.layer.Group({
                title: '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="sidebar-v2/ordisabeba/turistico.png"></img> <i class="fas fa-walking"></i> Turistico',
                layers: []
                }),
            
            ]
            }),
            
new ol.layer.Group({
            title: '<p style="text-align:justify">Descrizioni complete nella sidebar a sinistra dello schermo</p><p></p>',
            layers: []
            })

];
```

and **gis2web.js** by adding groupSelectStyle: 'none' in this line so as not to see the groups switch-on tick

```
var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({tipLabel: "Layers", groupSelectStyle: 'none'});
```

This is the result of the legend which, however, does not allow you to use the "popup on hover" function
[image]

the popups on hover does not work:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself, only this step needs to be changed in **qgis2web.js** file

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        if (layer) {  ecc.....
```

modify both `var onPointerMove = function (evt) {` and `var onSingleClick = function (evt) {`